# Spring JPA: Can Outer transaction rollback successful inner transaction

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In spring data, if i have an outer transaction methodA with @Transactional, which inserts into table A. methodA also calls methodB which is @Transactional with REQUIRES_NEW and inserts into different table.

If methodB inner transaction completes. And outer transaction, methodA, has failure after calling methodB, is it possible to rollback the inner transaction and the outer transaction.

Thanks.

Comment: No because of REQUIRES_NEW

Comment: Does spring + jpa allow the use of database savepoints?